# Bash script as .command not executing properly

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I have a simple script/command:

When I run it from shell:

```
 txt=testfile
 find ~/Desktop/Rory/Test -type f -exec grep $txt {} \; -exec mkdir $txt \;
```

The result is:

```
Binary file ./TEST.zip matches
and it makes a new directory named testfile
```

When I save it as a .command:

```
echo "cd: \c"
read dir
echo "txt: \c"
read str
find $dir -type f -exec grep $str {} \; -exec mkdir $str \;
```

chmod 755 and double click on it I get:

```
Last login: Wed Apr  2 20:44:14 on ttys004
zipher:~ Rory$ /Users/Rory/Desktop/CD.command ; exit;
cd: \c
/Users/Rory/Desktop/Test
txt: \c
txt
```

Then it proceeds to [**go to hell in a handbasket**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+to+hell+in+a+handbasket), recursively going into places the other command never ventures — I have to ^C it because it's gone bonkers. It doesn't create the new directory either.. where did I [**screw the pooch**](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/142312)?

Comment: So you are just trying to make a single directory in your current working directory if you find a file containing `$txt` anywhere on the tree?

Answer (score 1):

I have no specific explanation, but a few pointers:

- Does your script have a `bash` shebang line (is the first line of the file `#!/usr/bin/env bash`)? I've seen OSX act strangely without it.
- I assume `\c` in the prompt strings is meant to suppress the trailing newline - this won't work by default in `bash` - you either need to invoke `echo` with `-e`, or - preferably - just use `printf` - e.g., `printf "cd: "`.
- I suggest you *double-quote* the variable references in your `find` command so that the command won't break if a path or string entered contains embedded spaces or another char. with special meaning to the shell.

So far we get:

```
printf "cd: "
read dir
printf "txt: "
read str
find "$dir" -type f -exec grep -l "$str" {} \; -exec mkdir "$str" \;
```

There's more:

- Note that `find` process the *entire subtree* of the specified directory; if you only want to match files in the current directory, add `-maxdepth 1`.
- Be aware that `-exec` executes commands in the *current* directory, regardless of where the matching file was found - if you want all directories to be created in the input directory, use `-exec mkdir "$dir/$str" \;` by contrast, if you want to create the directory created in whatever subdirectory each matching file was found, use `-execdir mkdir "$str" \;`

Comment: +1, but since `echo` with options is so highly unportable it's better to not even mention it (unless it comes with a fat, blinking disclaimer in pink)...people should really stop using `echo -n`/`echo -e` and use `printf` like recommended.